# Please explain the ps -aef on rhel

Tags: linux, ps

What does `pts/2` indicate in the output below? Why there is no such for other `dd` processes?

```
$ ps -aef |grep dd
    root  6553672 15073352   3 02:32:19      -  0:01 dd of=/dev/lv01 bs=1024k
  padmin  9437410 16515110   1 02:43:32  pts/2  0:00 grep dd
    root 13828156 11010220   0 02:32:33      -  0:00 dd of=/dev/lv02 bs=1024k
    root 14155860 13828156   2 02:32:33      -  0:01 dd of=/dev/lv02 bs=1024k
    root 15073352 13762812   0 02:32:19      -  0:00 dd of=/dev/lv01 bs=1024k
    root 15532200 15925276   2 02:40:47  pts/1  0:03 dd of=/home/padmin/samp
```

Answer (score 0):

**pts** is a pseudoterminal, or a non-physical terminal, as opposed to **tty** which usually stands for a physical terminal devices.

The most common pts devices are SSH sessions.

Comment: Aren't pseudo-terminals usually called *pty*?

Comment: Agree with you somewhat, but the one without pts are those initiated throw remote application. The one with pts are initiated from the command dd of=/dev/ex1 bs=1024k through command line.

Comment: And is there any priority given to those with pts?

Answer (score 0):

These are most likely a result of cronjobs (or at jobs, other timed jobs) that don't have a terminal attached. Since cron is a daemon process, (nearly) by definition it doesn't have a terminal. Any child processes will inherit that no-terminal state

THe padmin job and the latter root job seem to be kicked off manually by people/processes in a terminal window.

Comment: Yes Rich. I did in a terminal window. Is there any priority given to these?

Comment: @Ratnakar not sure what you mean. You can change the CPU/scheduler priority of a process with [renice](http://linux.die.net/man/8/renice). Only root can renice with a negative value i.e. give the process higher runtime priority. Is this what you want?